# What is the meaning of -- -j 8 in cmake command

Tags: cmake

This is a similar question: [What does --target option mean in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896657/what-does-target-option-mean-in-cmake)

but the answer there doesn't explain anything about "-- -j 8".
What does it actually do?

Comment: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) search for "-j".

Comment: See the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633074/set-the-number-of-threads-in-a-cmake-build).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--` option means to pass the following options on to the native tool, probably `make`. For `make`, the `-j` option means the number of simultaneous jobs to run:

```
-j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
    Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j option, the
    last one is effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of
    jobs that can run simultaneously.
```

This allows `make` to use multiple processes to run  different build steps at the same time, likely reducing build time.

Answer (score 0):

The `-j` option tells `cmake` to run up to `N` separate jobs at the same time.

From the [cmake build options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project):

> The maximum number of concurrent processes to use when building.

Comment: Although correct, the reference is for make, not CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, make will execute only one recipe at a time, waiting for it to finish before executing the next. However, the ‘-j’ or ‘--jobs’ option tells make to execute many recipes simultaneously.